# Selenium waitForCondition

Tags: ajax, selenium

I am doing Selenium testing for the first time. On the homepage, I call some AJAX, and i want Selenium to wait for the element to load finish. I not sure it works, but i just type selenium and the waitForCondition are able to choose.

I not matter what I choose it always return "false". I do not now if the *waitForCondition* even work?

How can I test if it works?
And what am I doing wrong in this codes?

```
 selenium.waitForCondition("//input[@name='Report'", "3000");
 selenium.waitForCondition("//*[@id='MyTable']", "3000");
 selenium.waitForCondition("css=.someClass2", "3000");
```

If I implement by own class - it return "true"

```
private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

isElementPresent(By.xpath("//*[@id='MyTable']")) - return "true"

Answer (score 3):

`waitForCondition` is for Javascript calls only, not for waiting for elements to load.

What you have in `isElementPresent` is fine. I would combine it with explicit waits to be a bit more accurate about when an element is actually loaded and present on the screen:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html

Comment: okay, this work.

Do have a example of what you use in JAVA. I think this is alot of code that i need to write every time i use it.



WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
     return d.findElement(By.id("MyTable"));
    }});`

Comment: @Arran this solution works. I am upvoting it. Thanx for solution.

Answer (score 2):

**C#**

You can do it like this:

First of all you can set timeout value for the condition.

Then you can use the condition.

```
var Wait = new WebDriverWait(GlobalDriver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("xPath"))));
```

OR

```
Wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("xPath")));
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.isElementPresent(\"//input[@name='Report']\")", "30000");
```

This will wait for the element to be loaded till 30 seconds.

Comment: This is not working. According to @Arran, the _waitForCondition_ is for Javascript calls only. This is done through JAVA and IE8

Comment: It should work..For testing ajax based application I always prefer this method..Refer This Link http://www.seleniumwiki.com/selenium-rc/using-selenium-waitforcondition/

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    return (Boolean) js.executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
}
```

});

This will check if the jQuery library has any active AJAX requests for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Aaran referred you to the correct documentation for [Selenium WebDriver waits](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

You can see that they also write about ExpectedConditions class. This contains several helpful implementation of ExpectedCondition classes, such at the "is element present one", which is ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated .

Here is an example of using it:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php");

driver.findElement(By.name("word")).sendKeys("bird is the word");;
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='button']")).click();
WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement dynamicElement = driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#result p")));
System.out.println(dynamicElement.getText());
```

If you find it too verbose, why won't you just refactor it and extract a function which will accept the element locator and the webdriver, and returns you the element?

DriverWait.until() accepting an ExpectedCondition instance is like a way of passing a predicate function, just doing it through a class, or in the documentation example an anonymous nested class, since under Java you can't send a function.

The ExpectedCondition "function" you pass also returns a value, which can be useful in case you're waiting for a condition on some element (or some other value from the WebDriver), so returning it will save you an extra call.

Comment: By some reason the _ExpectedConditions_ is not knowed. Text: ExpectedConditions cannot be resolved

Comment: By some reason I don't have _org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions_ Where can i get that correct jar file? I do have org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition (with out "S" on)

Comment: What version of selenium are you using? I tested the code on 2.25.0, through maven, but it's available to download at http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: It is in selenium-java-2.25.0.jar from http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/selenium-java-2.25.0.zip

Comment: I forgot to add the driver: selenium-java-2.25.0.jar. You example work perfect now.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:

```
await().atMost(10, SECONDS).until(() -> driver.findElements(By.id("elementId")).size() >1);
```